# Create a multiple input search engine with pdo

Tags: php, search, pdo

This search engine is supposed to give me an output when I just search by keyword. When I search status only then it should also allow for a search when the status and keyword are given. If nothing is given it should fetch all properties in table but it's giving me an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindValue() on
>   string in C:\xampp\htdocs\accommoport\sch\search.php:72 Stack trace:
>   0)

How to finish this?

```
    $keyword= $_GET["keyword"];
  $stmt_search = "SELECT * FROM houses WHERE 
                        (property_city LIKE :param 
                         OR property_state LIKE :param 
                         OR property_address LIKE :param 
                         OR property_name LIKE :param)
                        -- AND property_status LIKE :status
                         ";
  $stmt_search->bindValue(':param', '%'.$keyword.'%');

  if($_GET['search_status']!='')
    {
        $status =$_GET["search_status"];
        $stmt_search .= "AND property_status LIKE :pstatus";

        $stmt_search->bindValue(':pstatus', $status);
    }


   $stmt=$conn->prepare($stmt_search);

  $stmt->execute();

  if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
  while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
   extract($row);
       # code...

       ?>
```

Comment: You're not `prepare`ing your query, you're just trying to call `bindValue` on a string (as the error says)…

Comment: First you need to prepare a statement before you can bind parameters to it.  Also, you seem to be very inconsistent in your parameter naming.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute method on a string. The way you bind params is:

```
$sth = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM houses WHERE property_city LIKE :param");
$sth->bindParam(':param','%'.$keyword.'%');
$sth->execute();
```